# I have Rails error with save method in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite3-ruby

[image]

I found this Error when call save method

My Rails Envi: Rails 3.2.5, sqlite 3.7.12 (in GemFile 1.3.6), latest ActiveRecord

Thanks You in Advance.

Comment: Do you use database_cleaner perhaps?

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: This is a Terminal Output 

rails console --sandbox <br />
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 3.2.5) <br />
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit <br />
1.9.3-p194 :001 > user = User.new(name: "xxx", email: "yyy") <br />
 => #<User id: nil, name: "xxx", email: "yyy", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> <br />
1.9.3-p194 :002 > user.save <br />
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1

Comment: Related to what @Agis said, does this help? http://yortz.it/2011/03/05/SAVEPOINT-active_record_-1-(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

Comment: @Agis How to database_cleaner ? I'm a newbie in Web Dev and Rails.

Comment: @OscarDelBen How to database_cleaner ? I'm a newbie in Web Dev and Rails.

Comment: I found this error while I'm testing my Model with '$ rails console --sandbox'

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord and newer versions of SQLite both support nested transactions, but the AR/SQLite adapter does not.

Further reading:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/6307
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153719/rails-3-nested-transactions-exception-in-a-child-block

A surprising omission from the docs, given that SQLite is the default DB!